# Larger font-size on nexus 7 (same effect if I zoom out/in on desktop)

Tags: html, css

I cant solve this problem. If I visit my page on a desktop or iphone/ipad it works just fine, but when using a Nexus 7 the font-size is for some reason increased (I **think** thats the problem) causing menu items to be too big and therefor giving them a new row.

This is how it looks when zooming out or on a nexus 7 (header-nav and footer-nav)

[image]
[image]

You get the same effect if I zoom out or in on a desktop, so you can test here: [solitude-online.com](http://solitude-online.com)

Comment: Do yourself a favor and set up Adobe Edge Inspector. http://html.adobe.com/edge/inspect/ It allows you to view the inspector of any of the devices you set up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using em units for your font-sizes. That is the best way to do it, however em-units are based on the default font-size. The default font-size is different on different platforms and operating systems. You can solve this by declaring a default font-size, like this:

```
html {
font-size: 10px;
}
body {
font-size: 16px; /* Fall-back */
font-size: 1.6rem;
}
```

Comment: Above issue won't make my application scalable. Which is another issue. I have same issue but I want to scale my app based on system font size.